# Creating and Editing word document by using a program

Tags: c#, java, programming-languages

I was wondering if it is possible to create a Microsoft Word Document programmatically (through Java, C#, or another language). Is it also possible to do things like adding text or changing the font?

I know that we can start other programs from the command prompt, but what I want to do is to create the document programmatically without using the UI of Microsoft Word.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in C#
Import the COM reference Microsoft Word Object Library

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

You can then set variables for paragraphs, tables, etc

```
        Dim oWord As Word.Application
        Dim oDoc As Word.Document
        Dim oTable As Word.Table
        Dim oPara1 As Word.Paragraph, oPara2 As Word.Paragraph
```

[C# tutorial](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/creating-word-document-using-c/)

I am unfamiliar how to do it in JAVA but I am sure it is possible

It can also be done in VB.net (naturally!)
[Tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316383)

Comment: I believe it is part of the standard .NET framework but I am not sure.

Comment: @PhiLho The path for the reference is C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office...So no? I want to try though.

Comment: No it wont because the COM Reference is somehow the ActiveX of word ,it only transfers orders from CLR to Word ,so no it wont work because you have the Link with Word but not the Engine !

Answer (score 2):

Dont know about c# but Java has the Apache POI project which supports reading/writing word documents.

http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html

Comment: Quick suggestion to OP - why not vote up the answer, rather than posting a "thank you" comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Open XML SDK 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx) to programmatically create a word document.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Word document version you are targeting. It can be Word 95 (classical Word), Open XML, RTF, etc.

RTF might be the simplest to handle, Open XML is normalized so the docs are available, .doc format has been reverse engineered, so it is known, and I think there is indeed a Java library to handle it.

The exact answer depends on your exact needs...

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Aspose.Words for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) or [Aspose.Words for Java](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.words-for-java/default.aspx). These components can work with .NET or Java programming languages respectively, and allow you to create or edit Word documents. Moreover, you do not need to install Microsoft Office on the machine your code is running on.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't understand the real purpose of doing that, the answer is YES.

Not only the word, any microsoft document for that matter. Usually every little functionality in office are made as COM/COM+ component. You will be able to have access to most of them from other programming languages. You'll be accessing them as COM APIs.

Microsoft documentation pretty much would explain on what APIs are available and how to program them.